# Does the visualsvn svn client respect the tsvn:autpoprops property?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Using the tsvn:autoprops to set

If not, are there any other VisualStudio SVN add-ons that support the tsvn:autoprops property?

Comment: This issue fixed in VisualSVN 2.5.0. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to inform you that this issue is fixed in VisualSVN 2.5.0.

Quoting [VisualSVN 2.5.0 changelog](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/#v2.5.0):

> Added support for automatic property setting using the 'tsvn:autoprops' property.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately it doesn't.
But I asked them to implement it, so maybe in one of the next versions it finally will...